# Is there any way to compile Manifest, Custom Functions etc in Puppet Agent?

Tags: configuration, puppet

I am looking for a way to compile Puppet Manifests and Custom Functions in Puppet Agent, like Chef.

Is it possible?

Use case 1. I want to check for file existence of some files in client side and do some actions.
(For example, If file1.txt is present, install this package)

Use case 2. I want to execute something for files with particular extensions in client side. All the files are in client side only.
(file1.txt, file2.csv, file3.txt, file4.py
copy only the files with *.txt extension to some other directory
)

How can I solve the above 2 use cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not too clear, as the relationship between your points is not obvious. I will try to answer :

#### Masterless puppet

There are several ways to achieve this, all using `puppet apply` :

- Store all the manifests files on the server and apply it.
- Compile a catalog on a the master, and apply it on your server using `puppet apply --catalog`.
- Compile a catalog using a [third party tool](http://lpuppet.banquise.net), and also apply it using `puppet apply --catalog`.

#### Adjusting the content of the catalog based on the client state

This is done with custom facts. If you are running `puppet apply`, you can also use the `file` function to read the content of a file. But what you describe doesn't seem to be a great use case for Puppet. Running commands on files or copying them is best done with a simple shell script.